# The data response send to ipay88 not the result i want

Tags: php, laravel

for the ipay88 should include a BackendURL need to return with the Response Code as "200" and the Response Data as "RECEIVEOK"/"OK" to acknowledge that the payment status has been received.

The expected result is

[image]

but the result i sent is

[image]

Here is my code for backendURL

```php
public function backendResponse()
{
    $expected_sign = $_POST['Signature'];
    $merchantcode = $this->merchantcode;
    $merchantkey = $this->merchantkey;
    $check_sign = '';
    //$ipaySignature = '';
    $str = '';
    $HashAmount = '';
    $orderID = $_POST['RefNo'];
    $paymentID = $_POST['PaymentId'];
    $paymentStatus = $_POST['Status'];
    $amountPaid = $_POST['Amount'];
    $transID = $_POST['TransId'];
    $remark = $_POST['Remark'];
    $errDesc = $_POST['ErrDesc'];

    $amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $amountPaid);
    $string = $this->iPay88_signature($merchantkey . $merchantcode .
        $paymentID . $orderID . $amount . $_POST['Currency'] .
        $paymentStatus);

    if ($paymentStatus == "1" && $string == $expected_sign) {
        echo 'RECEIVEOK';
    }
}
```

Could anyone help? i wanted to send the response data just only RECEIVEOK, without HTML DATA TAG. Thank you so much, really appreciated..

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is that method called? Why do you access `$_POST` instead of the usual request object?

Comment: Hi, the result is what the payment gateway support send to me. they say i should send back RECEIVEOK to them once the transaction was successful. but the result i send are what i show in the picture above. The $_POST is the parameter they send back to my merchant site.

Comment: And where exactly does the rest of that response come from? How is that method called?

Comment: You tagged this as `Laravel`, so it would be interesting to know how you configured the route file and if the response is the one that is generated by another route: you may be hitting a different script here. Moreover, a little more detail on how you reach the script (or you don't reach it)